# Pandas: Calculating using a window of 3 periods

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how to calculate next relation. The formula does this: it takes the last three
rows and then compute the formula with that data. And do this using a rolling window of 3

```
A   B   Formula Result
2   3     nan
3   4     nan
2   3    sqrt(3*0.33)
1   2    sqrt(3*0.33)
3   1    sqrt(6*0,33)
1   2    sqrt(6*0,33)
```

Formula:
[image]

[image: Formula]

What I have tried:

```py
df["Formula Result"] = sum((df["A"]-Df["B"])^2).rolling_window(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["Formula Result"] = (df.A
                          .rolling(3)
                          .apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(0.33) * np.linalg.norm(x - df.loc[x.index, "B"])))
```

Rolling over `A` and then reaching to corresponding `B` values over the index of rolling window. The formula corresponds to Euclidean distance between two vectors, so we can use norm of the difference. Multiplying inside the square brackets with 0.33 is equivalent to multiplying it with `sqrt(0.33)` from the outside.

You can also write it without `np.linalg.norm`:

```
df["Formula Result"] = (df.A
                          .rolling(3)
                          .apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(sum(0.33 * (x - df.loc[x.index, "B"])**2))))
```

to get

```
>>> df

   A  B  Formula Result
0  2  3             NaN
1  3  4             NaN
2  2  3        0.994987
3  1  2        0.994987
4  3  1        1.407125
5  1  2        1.407125
```

Comment: Thank you Mustafa. I'm searching for a solution kinda the one I put. Because I would like the column Formula Result to gather all the results and then return the full dataframe with the 3 columns

Comment: @Lazzal edited to answer to resemble that, hope it helps.

Comment: Mustafa how could add this modification to that solution? I want to multiply by 0,33 inside the root square. You can see how looks the formula above

Comment: @Lazzal You can put in front of norm, edited the answer.

Comment: Why are you using a np.sqrt()? We are just multiplying the euclididan distance

Comment: @Lazzal Multiplying inside the square brackets with 0.33 is equivalent to multiplying it with `sqrt(0.33)` from the outside. It is akin to `sqrt(a * b) = sqrt(a) * sqrt(b)`.

Comment: @Lazzal If you feel more comfortable without the wrapper `norm`, you can write `lambda x: np.sqrt(sum(0.33 * (x - df.loc[x.index, "B"])**2))`  inside the `apply` and be closer to the formula visually. The outputs are mathematically equivalent; put in the answer.